# <Noscript> tag not working in IE6. May I have some help, please?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, internet-explorer-6, noscript

Does anyone know why this doesn't work in IE6?:

```
<noscript>This requires javascript</noscript>
```

It seems simply enough, but unlike FF, IE6 doesn't show it when I disable javascript.

It's really confusing :( I thought the  tag was supposedly compatible acrosss browsers? Well, atleats from the W3 profile page for the tag. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Any help would be great!
Fiton

Comment: are you sure you really disabled javascript in IE6? try putting something like `<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test')</script>` and see if it triggers

Comment: Yep, tried all sorts of things. Javascript works, and can be disabled. I also did a test of the actual scripting ability like you suggested--which worked only for the scripting not the noscript tag.

Comment: BTW, w3schools.com has nothing at all to do with the real W3, the real deal is at http://w3.org/.

Comment: ^ Thanks for that. I actually thought it was official. Well, now I know :)!

Comment: How did you disable JS in IE6?

Comment: It should work, so you're doing something else wrong. Please post your HTML code maybe you have it hidden.

Comment: This may be answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761148/noscript-tag-isnt-working-on-internet-explorer

Answer (score 6):

Unlike, say, Firefox, you have to restart IE after disabling javascript for javascript to actually be disabled. If you did that but are still not seeing your noscript contents, please explain the exact steps you're taking to disable javascript.

Comment: very helpful, this is the sort of thing which keeps me banging my head against the wall for hours, because the answer is so ridiculously simple it never occurs to me! Thanks for saving both head and wall!