# noscript tag isn't working on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, noscript

I have a website with the `<noscript>` tag that works just fine on all browsers except IE (7,8,9,10).
After I disable scripting under the security settings inside Internet Options, On my PC only I can the the `<noscript>` content on IE, but on other PC's (almost all of them) I can't see the code. With these PC's we go with the same settings to Gmail's and FB's sites and we do get the warning for not having js enabled.

This is the HTML:

```
<noscript>
    <div class="noscript">
        JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use WEBSITE NAME in standard view.<br />
        However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser.<br />
        To use standard view, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, then <a href="">try again</a>. 
    </div>
</noscript>
```

CSS:

```
.noscript {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: have you disabled js on all these other PCs? noscript tag will only be rendered when js is not available - make sure it isn't (stick an alert in there or something).

Comment: perhaps the div is shown but out of the screen... try to add a top:10px and left:10px in your css rule

Comment: IE has this notion of different zones that have different security settings. Most likely the site is set to the trusted zone. It's especially likely if the site is in the company network.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap in `<![CDATA[]]>`?

Comment: @IanWood js is disabled on all other PCs. We get the warning on other sites with js disabled

Comment: @sly63 it's not CSS. We've checked it.

Comment: @Juhana that's sounds like something that I have to check. I'll do it now. Thanks

Comment: @Juhana You are right. These PCs had our website URL in the trusted sites lists. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Encountered this issue as well. I had this working in IE and then it stopped all of a sudden. What I found is that if your css is nested beneath a noscript tag in your actual css definition it will **not** work. If you use just a class name its fine.

I'm using IE 10 to test with and their dev tools to change the document mode to older browser modes to verify. Results may vary when actually using older browsers. Report back if this is the case.

**Example html:**

```
<noscript>
    <div class="noscript">
        JavaScript must be enabled ...
    </div>
</noscript>
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
// classes nested beneath a noscript tag are not applied by IE
noscript div.noscript {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 700;
        background: #D53333;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 4px;
    }
```

**Does work:**

```
div.noscript {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #D53333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember how I struggled with this problem when I was new to html. Though, I haven't found a solution to the problem, I found a really nice trick that does the job well. It has been explained below:

**Normally**, we use a **noscript** tag for this purpose. But this tag isn't supported in Internet Explorer.

So, instead of going the normal way, use a **div** tag instead of the **noscript** tag. Give it an **id**.
Later just above the closing body tag, add a script tag and paste there the below code:

```
var noscript = document.getElementById('_id_of_the_div_used_instead_of_noscript');
noscript.style.display = 'none';
```

**What the above code does?**
It gets the **#noscript** element and sets its display style to 'none'. Hence it disappears.

**How does this work?**
This works because if scripts are disabled, the script tag where you pasted the above code won't work. Hence the **div#noscript** will still be visible. But if scripts are enabled, the the above code will make the **div#noscript** to disappear. It works just like the **noscript** tag.

### See below an example:

Normally we do this:

- html: `<noscript> please enable javascript ... </noscript>`
- css: `noscript{background-color: red; color: white; font-size: 24px; ... }`

---

Instead do this:

- html: `<div id="noscript"> please enable javascript ... </div>`
- css: `#noscript{background-color: red; color: white; font-size: 24px; ... }`
- js: `document.querySelector('#noscript').style.display="none";`

Answer (score -3):

try this css

```css
.noscript {
   background: red;
   top: 100px; 
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: why should this work? moving it 1000px to the right might push it out of the screen. Also I strongly doubt that it's a css issue.

Comment: got it i think you should read http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp#gsc.tab=0    @aviramtsi man

Comment: [I think you should not read any w3schools article at all...](http://w3fools.com/)