# Hidden div is displayed briefly - how to prevent that to happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs on my page, one should be displayed if javascript is disabled, and another if the javascript is not disabled.

My problem is : even when javascript is NOT disabled, the div which contain message that javascript is disabled is briefly displayed, and 
it hides few seconds after, when page is loaded.

Here is the html (simplified version) that I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <!-- This div is displayed only if the JavaScript is DISABLED -->       
    <div class="wrapper-page" id="no-js">
        <p class="text-muted m-b-0 font-13 m-t-20" style="color:red !important;font-weight: bold;">
JavaScript has been disabled message.....
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end no-js div -->
    <!-- This div is hidden by default, and is displayed only if the JavaScript is ENABLED -->
    <div class="wrapper-page" id="wrapper-page" style="display:none;">
        <p>My regular content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper page -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backOffice/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- If JavaScrpt is disabled, then the main div remain not visible and only the div with the 
         Disabled JavaScript error message is displayed. -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backOffice/assets/js/disabledjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the content of the JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#no-js").hide();
    $("#no-js").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("#no-js").css('display','none');
    $("#wrapper-page").css("display", "block");
});
```

I tried to move the JS and jQuery on the top, I tried to switch the order of the html divs, nothing so far didn't help me.

Comment: place the javascript code  $("#no-js").hide();  at last line and without document.ready and try once..

Comment: @SandeepJPatel Nop, don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **noscript** tag for content displayed only if js is disabled

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <!-- This div is displayed only if the JavaScript is DISABLED -->
    <noscript>       
        <div class="wrapper-page">
            <p class="text-muted m-b-0 font-13 m-t-20" style="color:red !important;font-weight: bold;">
JavaScript has been disabled message.....
            </p>
        </div>
    </noscript>
    <!-- end no-js div -->
    <!-- This div is hidden by default, and is displayed only if the JavaScript is ENABLED -->
    <div class="wrapper-page" id="wrapper-page" style="display:none;">
        <p>My regular content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper page -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backOffice/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- If JavaScrpt is disabled, then the main div remain not visible and only the div with the 
         Disabled JavaScript error message is displayed. -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backOffice/assets/js/disabledjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution will display blank screen in IE 11 , which is not what I want.

Comment: Its weird. Tag noscript used inside body tag is well supported across all browsers, even old ones. Check your css.

Comment: I will man. I will write new blank page, and I will disable the js in ie and I will test it again.

Comment: You were right. I just now test the page ,and I got displayed the message in the IE 11. I am not sure for the older versions of but it seems that there is no better way. The only other option  that I had beside the noscript was css transition. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `noscript` tag as stated in waldemarle's answer, but here is an alternative:

Using `document.write`, you can put a container div around my body content with a class of js, then you can style js things from the beginning without it "flashing":

```css
.js .no-js,
.js-show {display:none;}
.js .js-show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script>
  document.write('<div class="js">'); // goes after start body tag
</script>

    <div class="no-js">hide if js enabled</div>
    <div class="js-show">hide if js disabled</div>

<script>
  document.write('</div>'); // goes before end body tag
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Look the following code

```js
  $("#no-js").hide();
    $("#no-js").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("#no-js").css('display','none');
    $("#wrapper-page").css("display", "block");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This div is displayed only if the JavaScript is DISABLED -->       
    <div class="wrapper-page" id="no-js">
        <p class="text-muted m-b-0 font-13 m-t-20" style="color:red !important;font-weight: bold;">
JavaScript has been disabled message.....
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end no-js div -->
    <!-- This div is hidden by default, and is displayed only if the JavaScript is ENABLED -->
    <div class="wrapper-page" id="wrapper-page" style="display:none;">
        <p>My regular content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper page -->
```

Is there any issues displayed in console.

Look if the file path used for javascript files are correct by verifying in source code.

Comment: This content is displayed just fine, because it is just one line. On my localhost, it work also fine, but when you try to access it from another computer via network, then you will see the hidden div briefly displayed.

Comment: That may be due to the path from which you fetch js file. In local host it would take the path but when accessing from other computer via network/ip path may be the issue. Try checking that.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<div id="content">
  Javascript is enabled
</div>

<noscript>
  <div>
    Javascript is disabled
  </div>
</noscirpt>

<script>
   $("#content").show();
</script>
```

noscript tag has been around as long as I can remember.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: I have tried that. IE 11 does not display anything within <noscript> and </noscript> tags. So the users that have IE 11 and js disabled will see blank screen. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761148/noscript-tag-isnt-working-on-internet-explorer